# Java Entity Manager - JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'db'

Tags: java, json, mongodb, entitymanager

I have this code already working:

```
EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
String query = "db.Band.find({})";
List<Band> list = (List<Band>) entityManager.createNativeQuery(query, Band.class).getResultList();
entityManager.close();
return list;
```

It returns a `List` with no problem. Now I want to sort that `List` by `date`:

```
EntityManager entityManager = getEntityManager();
entityManager.getTransaction().begin();
String query = "db.Band.find({something__id:ObjectId(\"" + myId + "\")}).sort({\"somethingelse.date\":-1})";
List<Band> list = (List<Band>) entityManager.createNativeQuery(query, Band.class).getResultList();
entityManager.close();
return list;
```

My console gives me this message:

```
org.bson.json.JsonParseException: JSON reader was expecting a value but found 'db'
```

I checked that my `String` was working properly in Mongo console and it did. Any ideas?

Edit: I tried putting "something__id" between quotes because it wouldn't work even without the sort part if I didn't (I just realised that), but now it says I am making an unsupported native query, pointing out the Sort part. Should I sort it after I already have it in a List object?

Comment: My guess would be that you're using the wrong query format for that particular API.

Answer (score 4):

This answer is late, but I was battling with the same issue for ages so perhaps it'll help someone else.

As per [this forum post](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=1039404), the keys and values must both be enclosed in quotation marks, so your `something__id` should be `"something__id"`.

Answer (score 3):

The thing is, if the type of the field you want to access is a `String` you will need to add quotation marks to the value of the field.

To give you an example, I've built a little DSL for creating queries without having to bother with the MongoDB specific keywords, such as `$eq`, `$lt` etc. and I had a similar problem. It can be solved by adding single quotation marks.

```
Queries.get(Query.where("name", Operator.is("'Kim'")))
```

Answer (score 0):

This might help someone, I was having similar error, and at the end it was because I was missing an index.

Answer (score 0):

What I was doing is : `@Query("{ {$or:[{'A': 10}, {'B': '20}]}")` which works in mongo console.It should be `@Query("{'$or':[ {'A':10}, {'B':20} ] }")` works perfectly.